# Need New Algorithm for Description

Tags: vb.net, modulo

Check Digit Calculation

Numbers and Letters in the Alphabet are assigned values. 0 - 9 is 0 - 9. A - Z is 10 - 35 and a space is 36.

Example String:
CA5B9AJ1564...

Calculations:
C = 12
A = 10
5 = 5
B = 11
9 = 9
A = 10
J = 19
1 = 1
5 = 5
6 = 6
4 = 4

Each Value is multiplied in descending order from 36 to 1, as follows:
36 * 12 = 432
35 * 10 = 350
34 * 5 = 170
33 * 11 = 363
32 * 9 = 288
31 * 10 = 310
30 * 19 = 570
29 * 1 = 29
28 * 5 = 140
27 * 6 = 162
26 * 4 = 104

=2918

2918 is then divided by 37 = 78 R 32
The Remainder of 32 is subtracted from the dividend = 37 - 32 =
5 is the Check digit

I need assistance converting the algorithm described above to a series of nested loops or private subs in vb.net.  I'd like to use the Mod Operator, as the formula we use at the company now is off by 3.  I've run 3 different strings doing this manually in Excel.
  Current Code:(off by 3 with test strings)

```
Private Function CheckDigit37(ByVal FieldString As String)
        Dim String36Value As Integer
        Dim PositionIndex As Integer
        Dim LastPosition As Integer
        Dim CharIndex As Integer
        Dim CharString As String
        Dim Value37 As Long
        Dim Remainder As Long
        Dim CheckDigitValue As Integer
        Dim CheckDigit As String = " "

        If FieldString = "" Then
            Return False
        Else
            FieldString = FieldString.ToUpper
            String36Value = RoundUp(FieldString.Length / 36)
        End If

        For PositionIndex = 1 To String36Value
            If FieldString.Length = 36 Then
                LastPosition = 36
            ElseIf PositionIndex < String36Value Then
                LastPosition = 36
            Else
                LastPosition = FieldString.Length - 36 * (PositionIndex - 1)
            End If

            For CharIndex = 1 To LastPosition
                CharString = Mid(FieldString, CharIndex + (PositionIndex - 1) * 36, 1)
                'If CharString = "" Then GoTo EndLoop
                Select Case CharString
                    Case 0
                        Value37 = Value37 + 0 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case 1
                        Value37 = Value37 + 1 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case 2
                        Value37 = Value37 + 2 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case 3
                        Value37 = Value37 + 3 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case 4
                        Value37 = Value37 + 4 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case 5
                        Value37 = Value37 + 5 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case 6
                        Value37 = Value37 + 6 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case 7
                        Value37 = Value37 + 7 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case 8
                        Value37 = Value37 + 8 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case 9
                        Value37 = Value37 + 9 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "A"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 10 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "B"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 11 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "C"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 12 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "D"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 13 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "E"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 14 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "F"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 15 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "G"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 16 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "H"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 17 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "I"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 18 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "J"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 19 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "K"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 20 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "L"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 21 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "M"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 22 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "N"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 23 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "O"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 24 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "P"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 25 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "Q"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 26 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "R"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 27 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "S"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 28 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "T"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 29 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "U"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 30 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "V"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 31 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "W"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 32 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "X"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 33 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "Y"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 34 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case "Z"
                        Value37 = Value37 + 35 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case " "
                        Value37 = Value37 + 36 * (37 - CharIndex)
                    Case Else
                        Value37 = Value37 + 0 * (37 - CharIndex)
                End Select
            Next
        Next

        Remainder = Value37 - Int(Value37 / 37) * 37
        CheckDigitValue = 37 - Remainder

        Select Case CheckDigitValue
            Case 0
                CheckDigit = 0
            Case 1
                CheckDigit = 1
            Case 2
                CheckDigit = 2
            Case 3
                CheckDigit = 3
            Case 4
                CheckDigit = 4
            Case 5
                CheckDigit = 5
            Case 6
                CheckDigit = 6
            Case 7
                CheckDigit = 7
            Case 8
                CheckDigit = 8
            Case 9
                CheckDigit = 9
            Case "10"
                CheckDigit = "A"
            Case "11"
                CheckDigit = "B"
            Case "12"
                CheckDigit = "C"
            Case "13"
                CheckDigit = "D"
            Case "14"
                CheckDigit = "E"
            Case "15"
                CheckDigit = "F"
            Case "16"
                CheckDigit = "G"
            Case "17"
                CheckDigit = "H"
            Case "18"
                CheckDigit = "I"
            Case "19"
                CheckDigit = "J"
            Case "20"
                CheckDigit = "K"
            Case "21"
                CheckDigit = "L"
            Case "22"
                CheckDigit = "M"
            Case "23"
                CheckDigit = "N"
            Case "24"
                CheckDigit = "O"
            Case "25"
                CheckDigit = "P"
            Case "26"
                CheckDigit = "Q"
            Case "27"
                CheckDigit = "R"
            Case "28"
                CheckDigit = "S"
            Case "29"
                CheckDigit = "T"
            Case "30"
                CheckDigit = "U"
            Case "31"
                CheckDigit = "V"
            Case "32"
                CheckDigit = "W"
            Case "33"
                CheckDigit = "X"
            Case "34"
                CheckDigit = "Y"
            Case "35"
                CheckDigit = "Z"
            Case "36"
                CheckDigit = " "
            Case "37"
                CheckDigit = "0"
        End Select

        Return CheckDigit
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question and your code right, it sounds like you want to generate the check string value for a given string (i.e., if it's 1, the check value is 1, if it's B the check value is 11).  I'm not entirely sure the code you posed will compile (I didn't try it), but by using the ASCII table and the `Chr` and `Asc` functions you can greatly reduce this code.

The ASCII values for 0 - 9 are 48 - 55, and the ASCII values for A - Z are 65 - 90.  Subtracting 48 from the first set and 55 from the second set will match the values your algorithm is applying.

Rather than do a bunch of rounding and string manipulation, I think it would be easier to loop through the string a character at a time, do the necessary operations and then convert the result to the corresponding value for the check digit.  Something like this:

```
Private Function CheckDigit37(ByVal FieldString As String) As String

    Dim CharIndex As Integer = 36
    Dim Value37 As Long
    Dim CheckDigitValue As Integer
    Dim CheckDigit As String = ""
    ' This will hold the character we're currently evaluating
    Dim C As Char

    FieldString = FieldString.ToUpper()

    For i As Integer = 0 To FieldString.Length - 1

        ' If CharIndex has reached 0 and we still have characters left,
        ' change it back to 36
        If (CharIndex = 0) Then
            CharIndex = 36
        End If

        ' Get the next character in the string
        C = FieldString(i)

        If (IsNumeric(C)) Then
            ' Subtract 48 from the ASCII value to get the algorithm value
            Value37 = Value37 + (CharIndex * (Asc(C) - 48))
        ElseIf (Asc(C) >= 65 AndAlso Asc(C) <= 90) Then
            ' Subtract 55 from the ASCII value to get the algorithm value
            Value37 = Value37 + (CharIndex * (Asc(C) - 55))
        ElseIf (Asc(C) = 32) Then
            ' We have a space (ASCII 32)
            Value37 = Value37 + (CharIndex * 36)
        End If

        ' Decrease the CharIndex by 1
        CharIndex = CharIndex - 1
    Next

    CheckDigitValue = 37 - (Value37 Mod 37)

    If (CheckDigitValue <= 9) Then
        ' We have a number
        CheckDigit = Chr(CheckDigitValue + 48)
    ElseIf (CheckDigitValue = 36) Then
        ' We have a space
        CheckDigit = Chr(32)
    Else
        ' We have A - Z
        CheckDigit = Chr(CheckDigitValue + 55)
    End If

    Return CheckDigit
End Function
```

This gives the value of 5 for your example.

I also used a longer string "CA5B9AJ15642ACKUQ02DA023MSAEWDSE924ADSCAA21" and got a CheckDigitValue of 21 and a CheckDigit of "L".

Comment: This works absolutely perfect, i was trying too many nested fors all at once...